# Login/Sign Up Transition Error

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble with the login overlay transitions. Everything works fine, but when you click on "Forgot Your Password?", then click back on "Suddenly Remembered? Login Here", it closes the overlay instead of going back to the login overlay.

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $login = $("#loginLink");
    $loginclose = $(".close");
    $signin = $("#signLink");
    $signinclose = $(".closesign");

    $login.click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".login_overlay").fadeToggle("fast");
        $(".signin_overlay").hide();
    });

    $loginclose.click(function (event) {
        $(".login_overlay").hide();
    });

    $(".forgot").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".forgot-password-overlay").fadeToggle("fast");
        $(".login_overlay").hide();
    });

    $(".linkRegister").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".signin_overlay").fadeToggle("fast");
        $(".login_overlay").hide();
    });

    $signin.click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".signin_overlay").fadeToggle("fast");
        $(".login_overlay").hide();
    });

    $signinclose.click(function (event) {
        $(".signin_overlay").hide();
    });

    $(".linkLogin").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".login_overlay").fadeToggle("fast");
        $(".signin_overlay").hide();
    });

    $(this).click(function (event) {
        if (!$(event.target).closest('.login-wrapper, #loginLink, .sign-wrapper, #signLink, .forgot-password-wrapper').length) {
            $(".login_overlay, .signin_overlay, .forgot-password-overlay").hide();

        }
    });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tn212b6x/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies with this function :

```
    $(".forgot").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".forgot-password-overlay").fadeToggle("fast");
        $(".login_overlay").hide();
    });
```

When you click on "Suddenly Remembered? Login Here", it fires this click handler as well since that div is inside `.forgot`.

Now this handler hides the `.login_overlay`.

**There could be many ways to solve it** but one such way is to give your form some other class-name other than `.forgot`.

```
<form method="post" class="forgot-form">
```

and modify the .login-click handler like this

```
    $(".linkLogin").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".login_overlay").fadeToggle("fast");
        $(".forgot-password-overlay").hide();
        $(".signin_overlay").hide();
    });
```

Check out the working here - https://jsfiddle.net/drecodeam/tn212b6x/3/

Comment: Ah, I understand what you mean. Thank you very much for the help.